# React Native: App no longer appears in Simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native

Does anyone know how to get a React Native project back into the Simulator?

I clicked on **Hardware**, then **Erase All Content...** with the intent of just running `react-native run-ios` again but now the app no longer appears inside the simulator.

How do I get the app appearing in the simulator again?

I tried running it from inside of Xcode but I continue to get this error:

`ld: library not found for -lPods-PROD clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` which is unclear to me because from within the command line I get a successful build.

Now that occurs when I `open AppName.xcodeproj`, but when I `open AppName.xcworkspace` and run the build it succeeds, but no simulator opens up.

Comment: Have you tried running the app from Xcode?

Comment: @Andrew, from `ios/` I run `open AppName.xcodeproj` and then I run build from inside of Xcode and I get a build failure saying `ld: library not found for -lPods-PROD
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: @Andrew, when I `open AppName.xcworkspace` the build succeeds but still no simulator opens up, but when I open up the simulator manually, I see the app is stuck on splash screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Clicking your simulatior, Add additional simulatior and delete and reinstall your simulatior. See if this works